# Access database of different computer in rails application

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application file database.yml ,the db points to my local db .

```
 development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: ca_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
```

if i want to make chanegs so that it points to some db in other computer ,how can i change my database.yml file.Do we need to make any other changes on the system where the db is present in order to get priviliges to access the db.

I'm using mysql

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: ca_development
  host: 171.168.19.156
  username: root
  password:
```

Error Message in log:

```
 /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Oct 18 12:44:02 +0530 2011
 Status: 500 Internal Server Error
 Can't connect to MySQL server on '171.168.19.156' (113)
```

Comment: that should be correct if the ip of the other computer is the one in host. you should also have permissions on the other computer so you can access the db...so what's the problem? is your db.yml not working?

Comment: @corroded ..not sure about the changes on other computer.can u just elaborate a bit

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: @Bijendra did you get any solution for this. I am also searching for this

Answer (score 0):

*how can i configure my database.yml also if any changes are required on the computer(regarding priviliges) on which the database is present.*

That sentence is a bit unclear, but just to make sure `database.yml` is for configuring how to connect to the database, it doesn't configure the database. So you tell it what type of database to connect to, where to find said database and the user credentials, but everything else has to be taken care of on the DB server itself. I haven't done MySQL in a rather long time, but `bind-address` in `my.cnf` let's you configure what interfaces the database listens on.